# How to use loops statements in unix shell scripting

Tags: unix

How to use loop statements in unix shell scripting for eg while ,for do while.  I'm using putty server.

Comment: You need to explain more.  What kind of loops?  Loops that count to something?  Looping over filenames?  Looping over a list of things?

Comment: Is the putty server part really relevant?

Comment: all the books on shell scripting available in the market & internet have a chapter dedicated to loops.please put some efforts in studying them before starting programming in unix.

Comment: which shell are you using? bash, zsh, dash, tcsh? If you don't know, what distro/version are you using? osx, ubuntu, debian, fedora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for: Iterate over a list.

```
$for i in `cat some_file | grep pattern`;do echo $i;done
```

while loop looks pretty much like C's.

```
$ i=0;while [ $i -le 10 ];do echo $i;i=`expr $i + 1` ;done
```

If you are going to use command line only, you could use perl, but I guess this is cheating.

```
$perl -e '$i=0;while ($i < 10){print $i;$i++;}'
```

More data

http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/

Comment: first one is bad example of a useless use of ls. for i in *;do echo $i;done

Comment: second example: i=`expr $i+1`  <--- no need to call external expr. $((i+1)) or $((i++))

Comment: I've change the ls for something else. 

Its just an example to show the for loop structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
items=(item1 item2 item3)

len=${#items[*]}

i=0
while [ $i -lt $len ]; do
  echo ${items[$i]}
  let i++
done

exit 0
```

Comment: Strictly, that requires bash rather than a Bourne shell; on many modern systems, there is no Bourne shell and /bin/sh is a link to /bin/bash.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the 'for' and 'while' loops mentioned by Tom, there is (in classic Bourne and Korn shells at least, but also in Bash on MacOS X and presumably elsewhere too) an 'until' loop:

```
until [ -f /tmp/sentry.file ]
do
    sleep 3
done
```

This loop terminates when the tested command succeeds, in contrast to the 'while' loop which terminates when the tested command fails.

Also note that you can test a sequence of commands; the last command is the one that counts:

```
while x=$(ls); [ -n "$x" ]
do
    echo $x
done
```

This continues to echo all the files in the directory until they're all deleted.

Answer (score 0):

to the OP, to iterate over files

```
for file in *
do
 echo "$file"
done
```

to generate counters

```
for c in {0..10}
do
 echo $c
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using for loop
max=10
for (( i=0; i<=$max; i++ ));
do
echo $i
done
```

Answer (score -1):

to iterate through a file in KSH

while read line ; do

echo "line from file $line"

done < filename.txt

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "sample while loop"
i=0;
while [ $i -le 10 ]
do
echo $i
 (( i++ ))
done
```